# Referencing HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking that if certain element could be referenced so, If I make any change to the one it also makes change in the other. For example,

```
<div id="trigger" data-referencedID="meter voltmeter ammeter vmeter">Trigger</div>
...
...
<div id="meter">
    <!-- Its children goes here -->
</div>
...
...
<div id="voltmeter">
    <!-- Its children goes here -->
</div>
...
...
<div id="ammeter">
    <!-- Its children goes here -->
</div>
...
...
<div id="vmeter">
    <!-- Its children goes here -->
</div>
```

Now in jQuery or JS:

```
$("#trigger").click( function() {
   $(this).addClass("animated"); // The same class will be also added to the elements defined in attribute.
});
```

I could do it like this:

```
$("#trigger").click( function() {
   var a = $(this).data("referenced").split(" ");
   for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      $("#"+a).addClass("animated");
   }
   $(this).addClass("animated");
});
```

But it is not good looking and convenient plus I can have more main elements with referenced attribute.

How can I easily add referencing in my document?

Comment: Use Knockout: http://knockoutjs.com/

Comment: @fatman I will take a look at it. Thanks ;) Seems helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class for all referenced elements like:

```
<div id="trigger" data-reference="reference_1">Trigger</div>

<div id="meter" class="reference_1"></div>
<div id="voltmeter" class="reference_1"></div>
```

And in your jQuery part:

```
$("#trigger").click( function() {
    var e = $(this);
    e.addClass("animated");
    $('.' + e.data('reference')).addClass("animated");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a reverse referring? Add classes in the meters which points to the trigger. This way you may add any number of meters which referring the trigger:

```
<div id="trigger">Trigger</div>
...
...
<div id="meter" class="ref-trigger">
    <!-- Its children goes here -->
</div>
...
...
<div id="voltmeter" class="ref-trigger">
    <!-- Its children goes here -->
</div>
...
...
<div id="ammeter" class="ref-trigger">
    <!-- Its children goes here -->
</div>
...
...
<div id="vmeter" class="ref-trigger">
    <!-- Its children goes here -->
</div>
```

And change the click handler for trigger as follows:

```
$("#trigger").click( function() {
   $('.ref-trigger').addClass("animated");
});
```

How about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an attribute on referenced elements:

```
<div id="trigger">Trigger</div>
...
...
<div id="meter"  data-reference="trigger">
    <!-- Its children goes here -->
</div>
...
...
<div id="voltmeter" data-reference="trigger">
    <!-- Its children goes here -->
</div>
...
...
<div id="ammeter" data-reference="trigger">
    <!-- Its children goes here -->
</div>
...
...
<div id="vmeter" data-reference="trigger">
    <!-- Its children goes here -->
</div>
```

And then you access all referencing elements this way:

```
$("#trigger").click( function() {
   $("#trigger, [data-reference=trigger]").addClass("animated"); 
});
```

The [data-reference=trigger] parts of the query match all elements that has an attribute reference with a value of trigger.

Comment: `reference` is not a [valid attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html). But you can use a [`data`-attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#custom-data-attribute).